# How Can i Update a Table (not datatable) with a Primefaces CommandButton

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces

```
<h:form id="tableForm">
   <table id="myTable">
     <tr>
       <th>HeaderOne</th>  
       <th>HeaderTwo</th>
       <th>HeaderThree</th>
     </tr>
     <ui:repeat value="#{myBean.List}" var="row">
       <tr class="myRows">
         <td><input type="text" value="#{row.fieldOne} required="required" /></td>
         <td><input type="text" value="#{row.fieldTwo}  /></td>
         <td><input type="text" value="#{row.fieldThree} /></td>
       </tr>
     </ui:repeat>
   </table>
   <p:commandButton id="myButton" value="Load" action="#{myBean.load}" process="@this" update="myTable" />
</h:form>
```

i want to load some stuff into my inputFields from my bean, but have one field that is required when i press save. So i have to set process to @this.

Afterwards i want my table to be updated. But i doesn't work.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try updating the form instead

```
<p:commandButton ... action="#{myBean.load}" process="@this" update="tableForm" />
```

since the table is not a jsf element but "pure" html, you can't use it's id in jsf elements

Answer (score 3):

Schäbo answer is right (+1) but Primefaces also provides a `p:fragment` component so you may update only the region you want to:

```
<p:fragment id="myFragmentReloaded">
  <table>
    ...
  </table>
</p:fragment>
```

and then

```
<p:commandButton ... action="#{myBean.load}" process="@this" update="myFragmentReloaded" />
```

Comment: awesome. Didn't know about `fragment`